# solrnet errors since new instalation (tomcat 8 / solr 4.10.0 windows server 2012 machine)

Tags: tomcat, solr, solrnet, apache-tika

I'm facing a problem with Solrnet a problem that seems random : when i try to use the solr.extract method to retrieve the content text of PDF/word... files (or solr.commit... ect)  i get the following error :

23-Oct-2014 23:03:03.729 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-58] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet default a généré une exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoader.java:1331)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1212)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.solr.logging.log4j.EventAppender.append(EventAppender.java:35)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.error(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:497)
    at org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.log(SolrException.java:120)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.ResponseUtils.getErrorInfo(ResponseUtils.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:820)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:434)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoader.java:1330)
    ... 32 more

here's my code :

```
        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SOLR_DocumentPJ>>();
        using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"c:\test.pdf"))
        {
            var response = solr.Extract(new
            ExtractParameters(file, "abcd1")
                            {
                                StreamType="application/pdf",
                                ExtractOnly = true,
                                ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                            });

            filecontent = response.Content;
        }
```

thank you for any help.

Just one more thing : we use SOLR 4.10.0 in a windows machine, not a linux one, maybe we missed something to configure tika correctly?

Comment: You seem to have cut off the most important part of the stack trace, namely what class it is that it can't find

Comment: "this web application instance has been stopped already" <- there's your problem. Start Solr again.

Comment: Well thanks, i already tried it and it works but the error come back after a short while. Previously i used a debian machine with a former version of solr / tika and didn't have this problem... A precision : i use this in a loop each time i want to index in solr with tika --> var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SOLR_DocumentPJ>>(); As for the stack trace, here's what i got from visual studio http://shorttext.com/5d93b5b1

Comment: Check the Solr log for warnings, etc.